# Random error in view page

Tags: views

I have created a view page with exposed filter and its randomly shows me some error like that:

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function i18n_menu_block_view_views_activites_activities_filter_alter() in  /includes/module.inc on line 1101

Fatal error: Call to undefined function i18n_select_block_list_a() in /includes/module.inc on line 1101

Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in /includes/database/query.inc
```

but when i refresh the page it disappear !!!
the problem that this error happens randomly and does not give logical reason.

Comment: There's got to be some pattern though. These things don't happen by random.

Comment: Do you have the i18n module(s) switched on? What's on line 1101 of /includes/module.inc? FYI, there's apparently no function i18n_select_block_list_a in any of the i18n modules (version 7.x-1.11), but there is a function i18n_select_block_list_alter in the i18n_select module.

Comment: in line 1101 is just a condition to check if module exist or no , but i am sure it makes none exist functions randomly there is no problem with module.inc
i doubt in something like buffering or caching , FYI if i refresh the page every thing works normally.